# MediaRouter Cast Button disappears when I disconnect from active session

Tags: android, casting, chromecast

I have casting that works great except one last part, when I am casting a video I am currently on the CastVideoControllerActivity and I click back, I'm now on some other activity but the mediaRouter Cast Button is still visible and active.

This is where it gets funky, when I click on the cast button i see the currently playing video and metadata but when I click disconnect, the button now disappears and now I can no longer access chromecast unless I restart my application. I can't figure out why the button is being set to visible : gone.  Tear down and cleanup works fine it's just that the button is gone and there is no way to bring it back. I'm using the Cast Companion Library.

anyone ever experience anything like this?

Comment: Do you see this with CastVideos-android project as well? Are you using CCL for cast button or you have a separate implementation around that portion? Does that happen all the times or it is once in a while?

Comment: nope just mine, I'll go over the sample app with a fine toothed comb and figure out what is going on here.   Thanks Ali again!

Comment: Noticed the exact same issue with my app. Did you find the cause and a solution ?

Comment: sorry i couldn't figure it out, but it stopped happening. I am hoping it was network related but I will let you know when I see it happen again I am going to be reworking this chromecast implementation this month.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue...does anyone find any solution?